# Can anyone ID this microorganism?

Tags: species-identification, microbiology, microscopy, protozoa

I found this microorganism in a wet moss sample taken from my backyard in Richmond, Virginia (USA). I took some pictures of it at 40x, 100x, and 250x. I'm not entirely sure what it is, but I think it's some kind of rotifer based on it's behavior. It anchors onto a piece of moss while hunting. It stretches out to catch food, and once it's caught something, it snaps back into itself.

[image: Image 1 - resting]

[image: Image 2 - hunting]

[image: Image 3 - recoiling after catching prey]

[image: Image 4 - resting]

Any ideas as to what this is?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Appears to be a [ciliate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciliate) protist called [***Vorticella***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vorticella).

[image]

<sup>Image source: [Wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Mikrofoto.de-Glockentierchen-1.jpg) (Author: Frank fox, 2010)</sup>

*Vorticella* always stood out to me because of their long, narrow stalk they use for anchoring with ciliate-lined bell-shaped oral end.

[image]

<sup>Image source: [MicrobeWiki](https://microbewiki.kenyon.edu/index.php/Vorticella) (originally from Haw River Program)</sup>

Fun fact from Wikipedia:

> The stalk is made up of the spasmoneme [also called "myoneme" above], a contractile organelle, with rigid rod filaments, batonnets, surrounding it. The coiled spasmoneme and batonnets serve as a molecular spring, so that Vorticella can contract. **The cell body can move hundreds of micrometers in milliseconds**. The spasmoneme is said to have higher specific power than the engine of the average car.

You likely mistook this for the more-commonly known [rotifer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotifer) due to the beating cilia at the oral end and tendency to anchor down, which are also both characteristics seen in rotifers. See [this SE post about rotifers](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/81953/16866) I wrote a while back which includes some nice animations.

Also, you can quickly differentiate *Vorticella* (which are typically free-living) from closely-related and morphologically-similar [*Carchesium*](https://microscope-microscope.org/pond-water-critters-protozoan-guide/ciliophora/carchesium-2/), which are colonial.

See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VOH2qOFoLto) ("Vorticella - Under the Microscope) by Nick Moore for various videos and some more info; [Journey to the Microcosmos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OQfSRk9uhYs) (YouTube) also has some good videos of *Vorticella.*